# Android Studio Support rtl

Tags: android, right-to-left

how to make the default language for android app is Arabic not English and make

support RTL is the default?
note : i add android:supportsRtl="true" in mainfast but that does not work

Comment: In what way does it "not work"? Are you getting a specific error message? Does it display LTR instead? Do you get gibberish characters? CJK glyphs? Does the app freeze?

Comment: it display LTR instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to add `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` to all of your layouts to make them RTL by default.

Also, you should run `Android Studio > Refactor > Add RTL support where possible` to make your layouts RTL friendly.

Comment: think you every thing work fine except the ActionBar it is still the same how could i change it

Comment: which ActionBar you can use default or you create your own ActionBar @EnaamRiyadh

Comment: you should be using `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`, see https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up

Answer (score 2):

✅ Use

```
configuration.setLocale(locale);
```

❌ Don't use

```
configuration.locale = locale;
```